# Utilizing Register memory in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I have some questions regarding cuda registers memory

1) Is there any way to free registers in cuda kernel? I have variables, 1D and 2D arrays in registers. (max array size 48)

2) If I use **device** functions, then what happens to the registers I used in device function after its execution? Will they be available for calling kernel execution or other device functions?

3) How nvcc optimizes register usage? Please share the points important w.r.t optimization of memory intensive kernel

PS: I have a complex algorithm to port to cuda which is taking a lot of registers for computation, I am trying to figure out whether to store intermediate data in register and write one kernel or store it in global memory and break algorithm in multiple kernels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only local variables are eligible of residing in registers (see also [Declaring Variables in a CUDA kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933702/declaring-variables-in-a-cuda-kernel)). You don't have direct control on which variables (scalar or static array) will reside in registers. The compiler will make it's own choices, striving for performance with respected to register sparing.

Register usage can be limited using the `maxrregcount` options of nvcc compiler.

You can also put most small 1D, 2D arrays in shared memory or, if accessing to constant data, put this content into constant memory (which is cached very close to register as L1 cache content).

Another way of reducing register usage when dealing with compute bound kernels in CUDA is to process data in stages, using multiple global kernel functions calls and storing intermediate results into global memory. Each kernel will use far less registers so that more active threads per SM will be able to hide load/store data movements. This technique, in combination with a proper usage of streams and asynchronous data transfers is very successful most of the time.

Regarding the use of device function, I'm not sure, but I guess registers's content of the calling function will be moved/stored into local memory (L1 cache or so), in the same way as register spilling occurs when using too many local variables (see [CUDA Programming Guide -> Device Memory Accesses -> Local Memory](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses)). This operation will free up some registers for the called device function. After the device function is completed, their local variables exist no more, and registers can be now used again by the caller function and filled with the previously saved content.

Keep in mind that small device functions defined in the same source code of the global kernel could be inlined by the compiler for performance reasons: when this happen, the resulting kernel will in general require more registers.

Comment: I am already using share and constant memory but still due to compute intensive nature of the algorithm, a lot of registers are required(>255, I actually asked this questions to calculate the number of registers required while designing the algorithm). If I store intermediate results in global memory and split the computation in multiple kernels then I am sure that I will be wasting a lot of cycles in reading and writing. Is it better to let the registers spill to the local memory? (so that if in the next generation GPUs, same algorithm will be supported if register per thread increases)

Comment: @Adarsh: you can't deduce the number of used register from the CUDA source code alone, it's a compiler choice you can limit with `maxrregcount` or using less local variables. When porting code from CPU to CUDA, consider also to change your algorithm into a more comfortable one for the GPU hardware. Splitting you big task into multiple kernels is the best approach for compute bound algorithms (answer updated): the less used register per kernel, the more active threads will hide load/store. nvvp will tell you if your kernel falls into this category. Don't "be sure", try it.

Comment: @Adarsh if my answer satisfied you, please sign it as accepted or clarify what is missing.